# Angular 2: How to dynamically change the display of *ngFor?

Tags: checkbox, angular, angular-ng-if, ngfor

I want to display an array of objects which have a `group` property in a list, and be able to display only those of a certain group depending on what the user wants.

In order to do that, I have checkboxes to collect the user's wish:

```
<div class="input-controls">
                <label>Select the group(s) you want to display:</label>
                <div *ngFor="#group of groups">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"
                               name="groups"
                               value="group"
                               [checked]="true"
                               (change)="updateSelectedGroups(group, $event)"/>
                        {{group}}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And then, I would like to be able to only display the objects with their `group` property selected. I first tried to only display the selected groups:

```
Selected Group(s):
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="#group of selectedGroups">
                    {{group}}
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I have managed to create a `selectedGroups` object, which contains an array of only the selected groups:

```
export class ListComponent {
        private groupsMap = {
            'Group A': true,
            'Group B': true,
            'Group C': true
        };
        private groups = ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C'];
        private selectedGroups: string[];

        constructor() {
            this.selectedGroups = ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C'];
        }

        updateSelectedGroups(group, event) {
            // groupsMap object is updated
            this.groupsMap[group] = event.target.checked;
            // selected groups are pushed into selectedGroups
            this.selectedGroups = [];
            for(var x in this.groupsMap) {
                if(this.groupsMap[x]) {
                    this.selectedGroups.push(x);
                }
            }
            console.log(this.selectedGroups);
        }
}
```

As shown, I have put a `console.log(this.selectedGroups)` to verify that my `selectedGroups` object really only contains the selected groups I want, and update properly when checking/unchecking a checkbox. And it does.

The problem is, when I check/uncheck or checkbox, the list of the selected groups doesn't update in my view. It get stuck as if `selectedGroups` was still equal to `['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C']` all the time.

Does anyone know why? Does it have something to do with the behaviour of `*ngFor`? If so, what can I do to have the behaviour I want?

I have tried an other method using `*ngIf` and `groupsMap`, but it doesn't work neither:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="#group of groups">
        <span *ngIf="groupsMap[group]">{{group}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would be happy to find a solution, one way or another. Any help would be really appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce. When I enable/disable a checkbox, the selected groups are updated https://plnkr.co/edit/lu3Sg1pEKSFBggyj0UW7?p=preview

Comment: OK, it seems that the problem comes from the fact that my component is included as a directive of an other component.
Indeed, your plunker is perfectly working, but when I copy-paste the code into my component, I still have got the same problem. Though, when I copy-paste the code into my main component, it works.
How does Angular 2 treat events and the refresh of component displays in a directive exactly? Do you know where I could find more details about that and how to deal with the problem?

Thanks a lot Gunter!

Comment: Could you extend the plunker to reflect your problem, then it would be much easier to debug and work on a solution.

Comment: OK, I have solved the problem, it was coming from another part of my code which was throwing my an error. I thought it had nothing to do with it, but I guess this error was stoping the execution of my whole component somehow... Anyway, thank you a lot for your help, it has been many problems on which you are helping me Gunter, you're the best! :)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working :)